# ASP.NET MVC on Mono

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono

I've installed MonoDevelop and latest version of Mono itself. But i still can't install MVC add-in since i have a dependency conflict: Core v2.0, Code.Gui v2.0 etc. But my repository http://go-mono.com/md/2.1.0/main.mrep doesn't contain ANY updates.

Is there any way to find the WORKING repository?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "2.1" version number is for current SVN trunk. It does not represent a fixed/stable API, so addins have not been released for it. If you build MD from trunk, you must also build the addins from trunk.

However, the ASP.NET MVC addin has been in main since last week, so it no longer needs to be built as a separate addin.

Comment: I understand that. But I'm under Windows for now. And it has no MVC built-in. And i can't really downgrade to anything below 2.1((

Comment: Ah. You'll need to either build MD from source -- which is pretty easy using VS, MD or SharpDevelop, or using MSBuild directly -- or wait for Lluis to release a new Windows build. Any new build will include the MVC addin.